# Basing on argument input, change flow of the code

Tags: python, argv

i excute my code with this:

```
testeClass = teste1(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], int(sys.argv[4]))

teste1.testeFunction()
```

I have that sys.argv[3] changes the code, if its "yes" or "no", if its "yes" it executes one function, if its "no" it doesnt start the function.
The function reads a .txt file.
I have a simple if to check that:

```
    t_m = sys.argv[3]

    if t_m == "no":
        self.STfile = []
    else:
        text = open(Sfile, 'r')
        self.STfile = [word.strip() for word in text.readlines()]
```

I want to change so that when i receive sys.argv[3] it detects if its "yes", "no", or a path to a .txt file, because i want to allow people to their own file.

Is it possible for the sys.argv[3] to detect if it is a pathfile that people introduced?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel My question is that if its possible for the sys.argv[3] to detect if it is a pathfile that people introduce in sys.arv[3]

Comment: Well, what if you use the rule: "everything that isn't either `yes` or `no` is a file path"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the only problem is if they make a mistake like mistyping "yes", so they type "yse", then the code is going to detect that "yse" is a filepath, and the code will crash

Comment: Well, computers normally don't try very hard (or at all) to detect typos. What the user typed is what the user typed, and we can only assume it's also what the user *meant*. So the real question is "if I am given a file path that doesn't actually lead to a file, how do I handle that?" and the answer is to catch the exception and do something appropriate to your situation.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel oh, that's smart. so when they type the sys.argv[3], if it isnt either "yes" or "no", i assume it's a filepath, but i do a try catch, and if it can't open the filepath it tells them to introduce the path again, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if t_m == "no":
    self.STfile = []
elif t_mo == "no":
    text = open(Sfile, 'r')
    self.STfile = [word.strip() for word in text.readlines()]
else:
    try:
        text = open(Sfile, 'r')
        self.STfile = [word.strip() for word in text.readlines()]
    except IOError:
        print("Error: File does not exist.")
    exit()
```